# Static variables in protocols

Tags: ios, swift

I have a protocol A which has a static variabe x. B is a implementation of A. In Class C I pass an instance of B and assigned it to a. How can I access 2 (value of x in class B) from it ?

```
protocol A {
 static var x : Int { get }  
}

class B : A {
 static var x: Int {
  return 2 
}
}


class C {
// instance of B is assigned to a. 
let a: A


print(a.x)
}
```

Comment: Is there a special reason for having `x` as a `static var`?

Comment: In that case you don't need static. Basically, your problem is that you're trying to access a `static` aka class-associated variable through an instance of that class. Remove `static` requirement and you're good to go.

Comment: It is static because for some cases I need to do B.x but in other   case I can't do that because A can have multiple implementation.

Comment: If you sometimes need to do `B.x` and sometimes you need an `A` specific implementations, then you should really think about splitting those two concerns. Because, when you do `B.x`, you're not really accessing your `a` property but rather the `x` property on a class B directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `static` variable belongs to the class, not the instance. You can refer to the class by calling `dynamicType`:

```
print(a.dynamicType.x)
```

Comment: How can I assign a default value to x so that I don't have to include in every implementation of A ?

Comment: Use the `getter` to access another variable which has a default value?

Comment: @2ank3th Use [Default Protocol Implementation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html)

Answer (score 3):

So things have changed a little bit since this answer was posted

```
type(of: a).x
```

Answer (score 1):

Within `class C` a is a property that holds an instance of a type adhering to `protocol A`. A static variable (otherwise known as a class variable) however is not accessible from an instance, it is accessible from the class, so you will access the value in the following way:

```
B.x
```

An instance variable would be a different matter and the code for this would be:

```
protocol A {
    var x : Int { get }
}

class B : A {
    var x: Int {
        return 2
    }
}


class C {
    // instance of B is assigned to a.
    let a: A
    init() {
        a = B()
    }

}

C().a.x
```

These can happily co-exist with the same variable names:

```
protocol A {
    static var x : Int { get }
    var x : Int { get }
}

class B : A {
    static var x: Int {
        return 2
    }
    var x: Int {
        return 2
    }
}


class C {
    // instance of B is assigned to a.
    let a: A
    init() {
        a = B()
    }

}

C().a.x
B.x
```

Comment: It is static because for some cases I need to do B.x (where I have a strong one to one connection) but in other case I can't do that because A can have multiple implementation.

Comment: See the final piece of code I've added where a class and instance variable share the same name. So that it can be called as an instance and a class variable.

Comment: Your answer is good but it requires creating static and instance variable. Do have a look at answer by Code Different.

Comment: yes, it clicked what you were after having seen what Code Different supplied.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, where I had a protocol with a static field that I wanted to be able to access from generic instances of the protocol.

My solution was to create an extension of the protocol with the behaviour I wanted:

```swift
protocol A {
  static var x: Int { get } 
}

extension A {
  var x: Int {
    type(of: self).x
  }
}

struct B: A {
  static var x: Int { 2 }
}

struct C: A {
  static var x: Int { 4 }
}
```

Now you can refer to the `static var x` from an instance context like this:

```swift
let instances: [any A] = [C(), B()]
instances.forEach { print($0.x) }
// prints 4 2
```